# Is there a way to prevent keyboard echo while entering a password in shell-mode?

Tags: shell-mode, keyboard, passwords

I have a test program that produces a lengthy output, so I ran it in "Shell".
However, at some point the test program prompts for a password, and when entering it, the characters are displayed, even if the program has set "echo off" (it's a Perl program that uses `ReadMode('noecho');`).

Is there a way to prevent keyboard echo during password input?

## Code sample

As the solution seems to depend on the actual code being used, here is a routine to "get a PIN":

```perl
# read PIN from STDIN
use Term::ReadKey;
sub read_PIN(;$)
{
    my $PIN;

    if (-t STDIN) {
        my $prompt = 'PIN:';

        $prompt = $_[0] . ' ' . $prompt
            if ($_[0]);
        ReadMode('noecho');             # disable echo
        print $prompt
            if (-t STDOUT);             # use a prompt
        $PIN = <STDIN>;
        print "\n"
            if (-t STDOUT);
        ReadMode('normal');             # re-enable echo
    } else {
        $PIN = <STDIN>;
    }
    chomp($PIN);
    return $PIN;
}

# use example: $PIN = read_PIN('some detail');
```

Comment: Does your program's prompt match `comint-password-prompt-regexp`?

Comment: Never heard about that ;-) Well, it's even worse: 1) `comint-password-prompt-regexp`lacks `PIN:` and 2) (even more worse) my program suppresses the prompt `unless (-t STDIN)` (which seems true for Emacs' shell mode).

Comment: If you want a tty, use `ansi-term`, but it's probably easier to change your code to always prompt with something like "Password:"

Comment: I also didn't know about `ansi-term`; when I tried it, it worked!

Comment: ...but `ansi-term` seems to have a limited or no scroll-back buffer, so I see no advantage compared to using the terminal directly.

Comment: There's also the `vterm` package, which solves that issue, but that's an external dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Emacs to behave like a terminal, you need to use one of the terminal emulation packages, such as: `term`, `ansi-term`, or `vterm` (and maybe `eat`, but I've never tried it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that Emacs' Shell mode does not obey the "stty echo" setting:

The Shell echos keyboard input independent of the state of `stty echo` (at least in 24.3.1).

```sh
> stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-onlcr
-echo
> stty -echo
> stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-onlcr
-echo
> stty echo
> stty
stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-onlcr
> ddddd
> stty -echo
stty -echo
> stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-onlcr
-echo
```

So the echo flag can be changed, but it has no effect.
Without a change in the code this won't work in Shell mode.